# how to program a pairwise multiplications between numbers from a given list of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, list, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

How do I make a program that multiplies the numbers within the list?

example 1: if given the list: [2, 5, 6]      return should be: [10, 12, 30]
example 2: if given the list: [1, 8, 10, 12] return should be: [8, 10, 12, 80, 96, 120]

so the numbers don't multiply with themselves and if two pairwise multiplication have the same number as a result, the number should only be written once.

I tried many things, but I am just incapable.

```
public class PairwiseMultiplications {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        getPairwiseMultiplications(list);
    }

    public static int[] getPairwiseMultiplications(List<Integer> numbers) {
        int[] Array = {6,2,4,3};
        int[] result = new int[Array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {

            int[] temp = new int[Array.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(Array, 0, temp, 0, i);
            System.arraycopy(Array, i + 1, temp, i, Array.length - i - 1);
            int product = 1;

            for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                product *= temp[j];
            }

            result[i] = product);
        }

        System.out.println();

        return result;

        int[] numbers = new List<Integer> list;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int[] temporary = new int[numbers.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(numbers, 0, temporary, 0, i);
            System.arraycopy(numbers, i + 1, temporary, i, numbers.length - i - 1);
            int product = 1;

            for (int j = 0; j < temporary.length; j++) {
                product *= temporary[j];
            }

            getPairwiseMultiplications[i] = product;
        }
    }
}
```

I know, I'm doing something terribly wrong, but I'm just stuck with what to do.

Comment: Does what you have compile? It looks like the method returns something, preventing it from ever reaching the part that uses the parameter `numbers`. (That should kick up a warning.) There are several acts of wrongness. Why not write in pseudocode (like plain English) first the steps you'd take for this task

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how it works with arrays. With lists it works similarly, but I'm sure you can do it yourself :)

You need the following operations:

```
Iteration 1: (1) * 2, (1) * 3, (1) * 4
Iteration 2:          (2) * 3, (2) * 4
Iteration 3:                   (3) * 4
```

So you multiply every number with all following numbers.
The outer loop is a for loop that goes through each number in the array:

```java
final int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    final int a = numbers[i];
    // ...
}
```

Next, we go through each successive digit, multiplying it by the current one of the outer loop:

```java
for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    final int b = numbers[j];
    System.out.println(a * b);
}
```

combined:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    final int a = numbers[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        final int b = numbers[j];
        System.out.println(a * b); // TODO: add the result to a list
    }
}
```